# MVC3 + Elmah = defaultredirect in web.config doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

I'm trying to link MVC3 with Elmah. Everything works great and all errors are handled and logged but i have problem with frontend for users with custom errors. I wrote global filter

```
public class ElmahHandleErrorAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        base.OnException(context);

        var e = context.Exception;
        if (!context.ExceptionHandled   // if unhandled, will be logged anyhow
            || RaiseErrorSignal(e)      // prefer signaling, if possible
            || IsFiltered(context))     // filtered?
            return;

        LogException(e);
    }

    private static bool RaiseErrorSignal(Exception e)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context == null)
            return false;
        var signal = ErrorSignal.FromContext(context);
        if (signal == null)
            return false;
        signal.Raise(e, context);
        return true;
    }

    private static bool IsFiltered(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var config = context.HttpContext.GetSection("elmah/errorFilter")
                     as ErrorFilterConfiguration;

        if (config == null)
            return false;

        var testContext = new ErrorFilterModule.AssertionHelperContext(
                                  context.Exception, HttpContext.Current);

        return config.Assertion.Test(testContext);
    }

    private static void LogException(Exception e)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        ErrorLog.GetDefault(context).Log(new Error(e, context));
    }
}
```

and I registered filter in Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorAttribute());
    //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

but when exception is raised, handler handled it but doesnt use defaultredirect path from web.config. It looking view in ~/Shared/Error.cshtml

My  in webconfig

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/NeutralError">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Home/NeutralErrorNotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

Any ideas? : |

Answer (score 1):

The `HandleError` attribute as default looks for the `Error` view in the shared folder and not works based upon the `defaultRedirect` properties set up on `customErrors` section. You can tell the `HandleError` to look for a different view name but I think in your case you want to redirect to some other action. I hope this will work (not tested),

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    base.OnException(context);

    var e = context.Exception;
    if (!context.ExceptionHandled   // if unhandled, will be logged anyhow
        || RaiseErrorSignal(e)      // prefer signaling, if possible
        || IsFiltered(context))     // filtered?
        return;

    LogException(e);

  // newly added
  if (context.Exception is HttpException)
  {
    if(((HttpException)context.Exception).GetHttpCode() == 404)
      context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/NeutralErrorNotFound");
  }
  context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/NeutralError");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working because its always pass if condition and return from OnException method

Answer (score 0):

Setting the View of your base class in your OnException method seemed to fix this for me.

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        base.View = "~/views/error/errorindex.cshtml"; // New code here... 
        base.OnException(context);

        var e = context.Exception;
        if (!context.ExceptionHandled   // if unhandled, will be logged anyhow
            || RaiseErrorSignal(e)      // prefer signaling, if possible
            || IsFiltered(context))     // filtered?
            return;

        LogException(e);
    }
```